# A Python regular expression to find the use of backslashes in C++ include statements, except when they're in a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a Python script to recognize where to clean up some C++ code. I'm having trouble coming up with a regular expression that will detect the use of backslashes in an include statement, but ignore the use of backslashes in a string that that happens to use backslashes.

Each line starts with a six digit number which is the line number in the original file. Here's an example, where the trouble I'm having are the `\n, \t and \"` in the string are causing the match to be a false positive:

```
000001#include "should\be\no\backslashes"
000002    QString code =
000003    "#include <QPushButton>\n#include \"some/thing\"\n{\n\tauto button = new QPushButton(parent);\n\tButtonStyle::ApplyButtonStyling(*button);\n}\n";
```

The regex should use groups to match the line number and the matching text.

What would be a regex that would match the first line's `include`, but prevent the false positive with the string that contains `include` and backslashed escape sequences?

Comment: I'm not trying to create something as complicated as a C++  parser. I just want to find style issues with C++ that can be found with regexes That is, I'm trying to create a relatively simple lint.

Comment: You could just match then remove the escapes later `(?m)^(\d{6})([^\S\r\n]*)(\#.*)` via callback

Comment: This could present problems with strings that span lines. You could however match strings as well as includes at the same time so that wouldn't be an issue. Example "\<newline>start \<newline># end string\<newline>" But, you might be able to qualify that with this `(?m)^(\d{6})([^\S\r\n]*)(\#.*)(?=\r?\n|\Z)(?<!\\)`

Comment: Also, the `#` starts more directives than just includes. Like defines, pragma's, if, else, endif, etc.. But, I don't think includes can span lines (not sure though).

Comment: It would help if you showed what you have tried rather than expecting someone to show you how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me:

```
regex = r'^(?P<line_num>\d{6})(?P<line>.*#include\s+(\".*\\.*\"|<.*\\.*>).*$)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just include the `#include` in your regex to only search for backslashes in include statements?

The following regex matches a 6 digit number at the start of the string if it is followed by a `#include` (with only white space between it and the numbers) and at least one backslash elsewhere in the string. It doesn't match the 3rd string because the `"` between the digits and the `#include` breaks the pattern

```
r'^(\d{6})\s*(?=#include.*\\)'
```

This example returns the desired result:

```
import re
strings = [r'000001#include "should\benobackslashes"', r'000002    QString code =', r'000003    "#include <QPushButton>\n#include \"some/thing\"\n{\n\tauto button = new QPushButton(parent);\n\tButtonStyle::ApplyButtonStyling(*button);\n}\n";']

for string in strings:
    m = re.search(r'(\d{6})(?=#include.*\\)', string)
    try:
        print(m.group(0))
    except:
        pass
```

Output:

```
000001
```

While your problem might be more complex than this, based on your question I think a simple approach based on this should work.